# why is this happening ? Image Provided

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write get tag name and id in console of chrome.Using:

"  console.log(document.getElementById("Main"))
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("span"))  "

after export in react js App.js file.But it shows null as ID  and  Empty List collection.

And When I do the same thing inside Component did mount to trigger it at last ....
It works as expected.

Why is this happening ? what is the right way to write it after export in react js.[image: Click Here to View Image]

Comment: that is because this `dom` element is not create or mounted yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Call stack is:

1. render()
2. componentDidMount()

So, first prints your null consoles and
then goes to render function, creates DOM elements
and then goes to componentDidMount where consoles are called again but this time with DOM elements.

Try like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){
           //Your Consoles
    }
    render(){
        return(
            //Your DOM
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Cant i write it outside componentDidMount()?  If yes Where Can I ?  are the codes that is giving me null ,executing before render?

Comment: I would suggest that you dig a bit deeper into React Lifecycle for the class component. 
It will give you a clearer understanding of the topic.